# Using User Input to control parameters in a Random number Generator

Tags: python, for-loop, user-input

I am attempting to write a program that generates random numbers, asks how big you want it, between 1-4 for example,  then I want it to ask how many numbers you want and finally ask you if you want to run it again. I am attempting to grasp the concepts of recursion and type casting, just trying to learn the concepts of Object Orientated Design with Python. I tried to glean from what I have read so far on the Learn Python Hard Way site.

```
from random import randint
def random_with_N_digits(n):
    range_start = 10**(n-1)
    range_end = (10**n)-1
    return randint(range_start, range_end)

# Here I am attempting to define the variables I need to convert keyboard input to int

size = raw_input()
intsize = # unsure of how to define this variable
intsize = int(size)

print "How many Digits?",
size = raw_input()

print "How many Times?".
times = raw_input()

# I want to construct a method here that sends my size input to random_with_N_digits(n)
# I need a method that runs the random_with_N_digits according to the input.
# while True:
reply = input('Enter text:')
if reply == 'stop':
    break
    if reply = times # not sure what to put here 
        print( def random_with_N_digits)
    else:
       # I want to tell the my method to run as many as much as 'times' is equal to


print "Again?"
answerMe = raw_input()

# here I want to have a if answerMe = Enter run the method again


print random_with_N_digits()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
from random import randint
def random_with_N_digits(n):
    s = int(raw_input("starting from.. "))
    e = int(raw_input("upto... "))
    l = ""
    for i in range(0,n):
        l= l +str( randint(s,e))
    print int(l)
    again = raw_input("print again?")
    if again == "yes":
        how_many =int(raw_input("how many digits?")) 
        random_with_N_digits(how_many)

how_many =int(raw_input("how many digits?")) 
random_with_N_digits(how_many)
```